# Sending and receiving values between C# windows and .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

For the purpose of registration for the product in C# Windows Forms,  I want to pass the license key from C# windows form to .aspx Registem page. After registering successfully in.aspx register page again, I want to send back success/failure flag from .aspx page to C# windows form?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? You could simply post to the ASPX page using HTTP web request and then get the response and parse it within your app.

Comment: how its possible to have the windows form registration process and can not add it to the aspx page ? The possible solution is to call the program from the shell if the program can return the output to console.

Comment: As the user Coder323 suggested you can have this with a Web Service or WCF. You can also have a WebRequest, a socket or even a hidden WebBrowser control and access the DOM's properties. There are many ways you can do this. I would go with WCF or Web Services if you want to do it right, and use good Technology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try having a Web service or WCF service which validates the License key from the windows form application with the Database?